# Unir varios polígonos en uno solo en google maps (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

¿Como puedo unir varios *polygon* en la API de **google maps** para android en un solo *polygon*?

Tengo varios polígonos para pintar en un mapa juntos, quiero representarlo como un solo polígono, para que en el momento de pintarlo no me pinte los bordes que limitan unos con otros y se vea como un solo polígono. ¿ Alguna idea para realizar esta tarea ?

Les dejo una imagen para aclarar mas mi pregunta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que compartieras parte de tu código, así la gente podrá echarte una mano más fácilmente. Échale un vistazo a [ask].

Comment: Has intentado algo referente a este problema? podrías agregarlo por favor.

Comment: No seria mejor que respondas a tu pregunta y marcar como aceptada para que no quede inconclusa ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado:)

He utilizado la libreria de JTS GeoTools http://geotools.org/. De todas las que vienen he utilizado la siguiente: jts-1.13.jar. Pongo el codigo por si a alguien le hiciera falta hacer lo mismo o parecido, le paso un listado de PolygonOptions del la api de google maps y me devuelve un PolygonOption con todos unidos.

Nota: solo funciona si las parcelas estan juntas por un lado.

```
public static PolygonOptions combineIntoOneGeometry(List<PolygonOptions> polygonOptionses )
{
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();

    List<Geometry> geometryList = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0; i < polygonOptionses.size(); i++)
    {
        List<LatLng> latLngList = polygonOptionses.get(i).getPoints();
        Coordinate[] coords  = new Coordinate[latLngList.size()];
        for( int j = 0; j < latLngList.size();j++)
        {
            coords[j] = new Coordinate(latLngList.get(j).latitude, latLngList.get(j).longitude);

        }
        coords[coords.length - 1] = coords[0];
        LinearRing ring = factory.createLinearRing( coords );
        LinearRing holes[] = null; // use LinearRing[] to represent holes
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon polygon = factory.createPolygon(ring, holes );

        geometryList.add(polygon);
    }

    Geometry polygonMain = geometryList.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < geometryList.size(); i++)
    {
        Geometry geoAux = polygonMain.union(geometryList.get(i));
        polygonMain = geoAux;
    }

    Coordinate[] coordinates = polygonMain.getCoordinates();
    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++ )
    {
        points.add(i, new LatLng(coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y));
    }
    polygonOptions.addAll(points);

    return polygonOptions;
}
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a todos.